# Counting number of times a given segment will occur in all subarrays

Tags: combinatorics

I have an array A having $n$ elements and for a given segment $[i,j]$ where $1\le i\le j\le n$, I want to count the number of times that segment will occur in all possible subarrays.

For example, let the array be $(23,\ 5,\ 4,\ 9,\ 11)$ with $n=5$, and I am being asked how many times $[1,2]$ will occur in all subarrays, then out of 15 total possibilities ($\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$) the answer will be 4. ($\{23,5\}$, $\{23,5,4\}$, $\{23,5,4,9\}$, and $\{23,5,4,9,11\}$).

Is there a formula for counting the same in terms of $i$ and $j$?

Comment: This is not very clear.  Can you explain what you mean by subarray, and what it means for a segment to occur in a subarray?  I don't see why $[1,2]$ "occurs in" $\{23,5\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I’m interpreting your question as follows:

> If $1\le i\le j\le n$, how many ways are there to choose integers $k$ and $\ell$ so that $$1\le k\le i\le j\le\ell\le n\;?$$

If your linear array is $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$, a choice of $k$ and $\ell$ corresponds to picking the subarray $\langle a_k,\ldots,a_\ell\rangle$, which includes $\langle a_i,\ldots,a_j\rangle$ if and only if $k\le i$ and $j\le\ell$.

There are $i$ integers in the interval $[1,i]$ and $n-j+1$ in the interval $[j,n]$; $k$ can be any of the $i$ integers in $[1,i]$, and $\ell$ can be any of the $n-j+1$ integers in $[j,n]$, so there are $i(n-j+1)$ choices for the pair $\langle k,\ell\rangle$.